# animating a hide/show of UIView following Apple example

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm trying to do some simple animation.  I have a UIViewController that has two views in it, that are subviews of the main view.  (In Interface Builder, I created two UIView objects, both their own subview of the view that gets created automatically in the .xib from the UIViewController template).  I have the second view hidden in IB.  The View Controller gets presented modally as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet.  When a button is pressed, I want to  hide the first view, go to the second view.  I tried following's Apple example here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Listings/Classes_ViewTransitionsAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007411-Classes_ViewTransitionsAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4

Here is my code when the button is pressed:

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.duration = 0.75;
    transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    self.FirstScreen.hidden = YES;
    self.SecondScreen.hidden = NO;
```

Unfortunately, I do not get any animation.  I get the hide/unhide I want, but no transitioning animation.  So my first question is what am I doing wrong in code?

A side question is, can you do something like this with blocks?  I've done some simple animations in blocks like changing the alpha with

```
[UIView animationWithDuration... ]
```

But wasn't sure how to do the above transition with blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animating `hidden` property try to animate:

```
self.FirstScreen.alpha = 0.0;
self.SecondScreen.alpha = 1.0;
```

or

```
self.FirstScreen.layer.opacity = 0.0;
self.SecondScreen.layer.opacity = 1.0;
```

from here - [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)

The following properties of the UIView class are animatable:

```
@property frame   
@property bounds   
@property center  
@property transform   
@property alpha   
@property backgroundColor   
@property contentStretch
```

---

Another solution:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         self.FirstScreen.alpha = 0.0;
                         self.SecondScreen.alpha = 1.0; 
                     }
                     completion:nil];
```

Comment: I tried the alpha opacity and unfortunately it doesn't work.  Is it because the view is presented as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet?

Comment: good. At first, your animation will aplly only to one view in this line - `[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];`. And this view would be a `self.view`. Before this line put `self.view.layer.opacity = 0.0;` and you can see effect. Disandvantages of this approach is only one view animating. The best way to your aims is to use animating with blocks. Waiting please, i will update my answer.

Comment: It must be something I'm doing wrong elsewhere since I understand your block and see why it would in other cases, but it does not seem to work here unfortunately :-\...